# Not able to connect with remote MySQL server from another server in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a PHP script on my local machine and created database connection from remote server. It is working fine on my localhost. But when I upload that script on server, script is unable to connect with server.

Codebase server and MySQL server are different but on same LAN. I am getting below error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied

Comment: have you uploaded the db, and set up the credentials?

Comment: Does the server accept remote connections? Do you have IP restrictions in place? Have you checked the user and password?

Comment: The server where is MySQL must have open port so the script can reach it from outside. The user you have on MySQL must have a privilege to connect not only from local host (user%*)

Comment: But I am able to connect with DB server via terminal with same credentials from codebase server.

Comment: turn off SELinux or set it up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this:

- **Firewall** of the server must be set-up to enable incomming connections on port **3306**
- You must have a user in **MySQL** who is allowed to connect from `%` (any host) (see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for details)

Comment: You are fast :)

Comment: But I am able to connect with DB server via terminal with same credentials from codebase server.